# C++ is there a difference between dereferencing and using dot operator, vs using the arrow operator

Tags: c++, dereference

Let's say I have the following variable:

```
MyObject* obj = ...;
```

If this object has the field `foo`, there are two ways of accessing it:

1. `obj->foo`
2. `(*obj).foo`

Are there any differences between using one method over the other. Or is the first method just syntactic sugar for the second?

I was thinking maybe the first one could cause the copy constructor of the object to be called since it is now holding onto the value.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's just syntactic sugar. At least in your case it is; the behavior might be different when overloaded operators are involved.

Comment: "I was thinking maybe the first one could cause the copy constructor of the object to be called since it is now holding onto the value." Why do you think so?

Comment: For overloaded `operator->`, the `->` has the "drill down" property where it is applied recursively until the resulting object is a pointer.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460730/4641116

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Pass by value causes copy constructor to be called, so I was thinking that perhaps dereferencing is passing the object by value to the piece of code that is dereferencing it. Just a thought, I figured that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference when `obj` is a pointer.

If `obj` is an object of some class, `obj->foo` will call `operator->()` and `(*obj).foo` will call `operator*()`. You could in theory overload these to do totally different behavior, but that would be a very badly designed class.

Answer (score 6):

According to [§7.6.1.5 ¶2 of the ISO C++20 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ref#2), the expression `obj->foo` is converted to `(*obj).foo`. So it is just syntactic sugar. Both are equivalent.

> I was thinking maybe the first one could cause the copy constructor of the object to be called since it is now holding onto the value.

No constructor will be called, because no new object is created.

Answer (score 3):

> is the first method just syntactic sugar for the second?

Yes.

> I was thinking maybe the first one could cause the copy constructor of the object to be called

No.

---

Technically, there is a difference that `operator.` cannot be overloaded for classes while `operator->` can be overloaded. Operators `->` and `*` should be overloaded such that `it->foo` and `(*it).foo` remain equivalent, although the language technically doesn't enforce that.